# Python Widget and sizepolicy

Tags: python

I am using PyQt5. I created a window and then added a widget. And set the sizepolicy of the widget to be expanding horizontally, but not vertically. I purposefully did not add any QLayout() on top of my main window to check if the sizepolicy works fine or not. To my surprise it didn't, but when I added the QLayout() it did work.

Why did it surprise me? I checked official documentation of QT and it says that:

> If there is a QLayout that manages this widget's children, the size policy specified by that layout is used. If there is no such QLayout, the result of this function is used.

(I am not clear what is the function they are referring to)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/41pwc.jpg

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop

What I got from the documentation is that if there is a QLayout on top of a window and then the layout holds more widgets, the sizepolicy of the widgets that the layout holds will be controlled by QLayout(). If there is no QLayout(), then some individual function related to sizepolicy of the widget is used.

In my code I tried to implement that scenario. But it is not working as per my understanding of the official documentation.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
menu_bar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(window)
menu_bar.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 22)
size_policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
menu_bar.setSizePolicy(size_policy)
menu_bar.addMenu("File")
menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")

# lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
# lay.addWidget(menu_bar)
# window.setLayout(lay)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to apply a layout to a menu bar. Usually, you just add items and you're done. I like the [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) tutorials. They are short and to the point. S/he has a [page on layouts](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/). Also, you can get an understanding of layouts from Qt Designer, which usually is bundled with PyQt